# Laravel. Можно ли получить ссылку к файлу в /config?

Tags: laravel

Настраиваю подключение к Google BigQuery. Для подключения используется json с настройками. Логично кинуть его к конфигам в `/config`. А как потом его получить? Я Laravel только начал изучать, как я понял, это можно сделать с помощью `Storage`, предварительно прописав линки. Но не до папки `config`. Сейчас в `/config` я создал файл с кодом:

```
return [
    'json' => file_get_contents('bigquery.json')
];
```

и хотел получать его стандартным методом:

```
config('googlebigquery.json');
```

Однако выдается ошибка `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

Как правильно указать путь до файла?

Comment: Должно работать. Файл `config/googlebigquery.php` есть?

Comment: Да, конечно он создан

Comment: `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/bigquery.json')`

Comment: Ещё по мимо волшебной константы в ларе есть методы основанные на ней, base_path, public_path, storage_path, app_path, database_path, resource_path, config_path...